# TS file generated by Typewriter is not a module

Tags: c#, typescript, typewriter

I used the Typewriter extension in Visual Studio to generate a model (Account.ts), but when I try to import the model in another class it fails. What am I doing wrong?

```
import { Account } from '../../models/greencard/Account';
```

Error

```
'C:/Users/me/Desktop/_REPOS/stuff/ClientApp/src/app/models/greencard/Account.ts' is not a module.
```

Typewriter file

```
${
    // Enable extension methods by adding using Typewriter.Extensions.*
    using Typewriter.Extensions.Types;

    // Uncomment the constructor to change template settings.
    //Template(Settings settings)
    //{
    //    settings.IncludeProject("Project.Name");
    //    settings.OutputExtension = ".tsx";
    //}

    // Custom extension methods can be used in the template by adding a $ prefix e.g. $LoudName
    string LoudName(Property property)
    {
        return property.Name.ToUpperInvariant();
    }
}
module InvWebOps.EFModels.TypewriterTSTFiles {

templates e.g. $Properties[public $name: $Type][, ]

    // More info: http://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/

$Classes(Account)[
    export class $Name {
        $Properties[
        // $LoudName
        public $name: $Type = $Type[$Default];]
    }]
}
```

Autogenerated Account.ts

```
module InvWebOps.EFModels.TypewriterTSTFiles {

    // More info: http://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/


    export class Account {

        // ID
        public id: number = 0;
     ......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer

You can access the `Account` class in some other file by [using its namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html).

```
namespace InvWebOps.EFModels.TypewriterTSTFiles {
    const account = new Account();
}

// the deprecated `module` keyword also works
module InvWebOps.EFModels.TypewriterTSTFiles {
    const account = new Account();
}

// a fully qualified name also works
const account = new InvWebOps.EFModels.TypewriterTSTFiles.Account();
```

#### More Details

> What am I doing wrong?

The keyword `module` [has been deprecated in favor of](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) `namespace`. Both keywords mean the same thing, but the second one is less confusing. The official TypeScript docs say this about namespaces:

> Namespaces are simply named JavaScript objects in the global namespace. This makes namespaces a very simple construct to use. They can span multiple files ... [and] ... can be a good way to structure your code in a Web Application...

The generated `Account` code does two things:

1. Adds the `InvWebOps.EFModels.TypewriterTSTFiles` namespace to the global scope.
2. Exports an `Account` class from that namespace.

Anything that gets exported from a namespace is only accessible from within that namespace. So, whenever a line of code needs to access the `Account` class, the line of code needs to use the `Account` class's namespace. The short answer shows three ways to do that.