# Trying to add a class wrapped in a module declaration to angular

Tags: angular, typescript, typewriter

I used Typewriter to create an typescript class from my C# code. When I try to reference it in my angular project via import it says module does not exist or namespace not recognized if I use namespace.

What is the proper way to add class to my project so I can use it in other files?

```js
module Budget.Infrastructure.Model {
        // $Classes/Enums/Interfaces(filter)[template][separator]
        // filter (optional): Matches the name or full name of the current item. * = match any, wrap in [] to match attributes or prefix with : to match interfaces or base classes.
        // template: The template to repeat for each matched item
        // separator (optional): A separator template that is placed between all templates e.g. $Properties[public $name: $Type][, ]
    
        // More info: http://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/
    
        
        export class User {
            
            // ID
            public id: string = null;
            // FIRSTNAME
            public firstName: string = null;
            // LASTNAME
            public lastName: string = null;
            // EMAIL
            public email: string = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Angular or Angularjs?

Comment: Maybe this helps you? HINT: module is now actually namespace in TS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55068604/ts-file-generated-by-typewriter-is-not-a-module

Answer (score 0):

you have to export the module

```js
export module Budget.Infrastructure.Model {
        // $Classes/Enums/Interfaces(filter)[template][separator]
        // filter (optional): Matches the name or full name of the current item. * = match any, wrap in [] to match attributes or prefix with : to match interfaces or base classes.
        // template: The template to repeat for each matched item
        // separator (optional): A separator template that is placed between all templates e.g. $Properties[public $name: $Type][, ]
    
        // More info: http://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/
    
        
        export class User {
            
            // ID
            public id: string = null;
            // FIRSTNAME
            public firstName: string = null;
            // LASTNAME
            public lastName: string = null;
            // EMAIL
            public email: string = null;
        }
}
```

and you can import like this

```js
import {Budget} from "./test";
import User = Budget.Infrastructure.Model.User;
```

Comment: Due to the class being autogenerated by typewriter I dont think I have an option to add the export keyword before module. Is there any another way to do it or am I out of luck?

Comment: that I know of, there are no other ways :(

Comment: I was able to change the statement in typewriter, but seem to be having some additional problems getting it to be recognized. For the import, why is it Budget instead of Budget.Infrastructure.Model?